# Print each record per page in stimulsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net, stimulsoft

I design an application to create pdf file (I used stimulsoft for this purpose), my template has 2 fix page, I wanna read for example 10 records from SQL Database and create this 2 pages for every records (totally I will have 20 page).
Could you please help me?

thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this issue, when you add "Business Object" to your design, you have to set **"New Page After"** attribute to **"True"** to use every record per page, but I want print page #2 after every pages.